# File upload css issue

Tags: html, file-upload

I want to have a file upload using php. my problem simple in the CSS I make:

```
<input name="ufile" type="file" id="ufile" size="50" />
```

it just show the browse button.
I want to have like a text box with the browse button to show the file address after upload it.
I know that :

```
<input name="ufile" type="file" id="ufile" size="50" />
```

will show the text box as will as the browse button but I tried it on firefox and chrome nothing showed just the button not text box. does anybody have any idea about that? why the text box is not shown???

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your html above and it worked in Firefox and IE 9. My guess is that you have some CSS within your webpage that is affecting the file input. You could try use Firebug of developer tools in Chrome to inspect the input to see what css rules are being applied.

Comment: I make a page just to check this issue and there is not css conflict there. I tested on firefox and chrome not shows but it shows on opera and IE